# Find class on and run function on current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Completely out of my comfort zone here and I'm 112% certain what I've got so far is absolute garbage and wrong.  I've never used ajax before and Google is proving very confusing so I was hoping somebody with a bit of knowledge could help!!

Essentially what I want to do is search a url for a specific class.  If the url has that class, then I want to run a function on my current page.

So in my example.  I want to check that a movie is in stock on play.com.  If it's in stock (it is) I want my border to change to red.

**I've fiddled it here:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Lmk8wdx/

**Here's my code - Sorry if it's insanely wrong!!**

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.play.com/stores/EntertainmentStore/listing/747490324',
    success: function(result) {
        var $stockLevel = $(result).find('.mtm');
        if ($($stockLevel).hasClass('in-stock')){
            $('#container').addClass('.active');
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I'm ridiculously confused!!

Comment: Your issue is that play.com doesn't allow your AJAX request. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is denied

Comment: Did you hear about same domain policy?

Comment: I've been using fiddler (not sure if that changes anything) and been working on the same domain and it's not working

Comment: Do you work at Rakuten England?

Comment: Hi, No I don't, I was just using their site as an example so it makes sense that I'm looking for a class on that page and then for a function to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one cannot send AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) request to a different domain. `JSONP` is really a simple trick to overcome XMLHttpRequest same domain policy. So you need to use `jsonp` as datatype.

so try this:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://www.play.com/stores/EntertainmentStore/listing/747490324',
  success: function(result) {
    var $stockLevel = $(result).find('.mtm');
    if ($($stockLevel).hasClass('in-stock')){
        $('#container').addClass('.active');
    }
  }
});
```

with this datatype, ajax hopes for `jsonp` answer, so the request should return something in jsonp form. in this particular case, the ajax request is returning the whole html document which starts with `<!document>...`. thats why the error in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: @zod yep, call is being made. it is just another bug which doesnot relate to ajax call.

Comment: yep. they dont return jsonp

Comment: @zod yep :D it is returning the whole page (html page), but ajax hopes for jsonp. so html document starts with ``<!doctype>..``, that first ``<`` cannot be a jsonp, thus the error in console.

Comment: Sorry for sounding stupid.  But I still can't manage to get this to work.  I've copied everything across as is, other than fixing the ".active" in the function to just "active".  Thank you!

Comment: Your succes callback will only work if the request to that play website a jsonp get jsonp response which is not the case in your code. Thats why it is not writing.